# Highcharts y axis and x axis display

Tags: highcharts

I'm stuck with highcharts. I have 2 problems

- For design purpose I need to display the y axis on the left also.
- The x axis, is set on `datetime`. and I need to display the last value. Also display a grid line above this last value. The problem is that it goes 5 by 5 years and the last grid needs to be only 3 years wide.

If anyone has some ideas on how to do that. I'm lost between `showlabels` and `tickintervals`, and donot seem to find the solution.

Comment: Highcharts has many example: why don't you fork this example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes/ with your problem

Comment: well...so far I don't even know what I've tried anymore. Here's a fiddle with my last attempt on line 38 and 39 : http://jsfiddle.net/HowTo/CsgAv/  ...it didn't work, I've also tried using dataLabels...It didn't get me anywhere...:/. is there anyway to use a formatter for the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an xAxis property tickPositions you can use, to specify them explicitly.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions

http://jsfiddle.net/CsgAv/1/

```
xAxis : {
    tickPositions: [
                Date.UTC(1980,0,1),
                Date.UTC(1990,0,1),
                Date.UTC(2000,0,1),
                Date.UTC(2010,0,1),
                Date.UTC(2013,0,1)
    ],
    ....
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! I'd add a vote but I don't have enough 'reputations'(still havn't figure out what that is...), but know that I'm definetly mentally voting for your comment ;) Thanks a lot!